# Rolling Arrays as a possible solution to a rolling window in SAS

Tags: arrays, loops, sas, do-loops

I am trying to calculate the dosage of a particular drug for a population to see if any member in this population is over a certain threshold for any 90 consecutive days. So to do this I am thinking that I am going to need to make a arraty that looks at the strengh of this drug over 90 days from an index and if they are all '1' then they get a 'pass', and somehow put this into a do loop to look at all of the potential 90 day windows for a year i=1...i=275 to see if a member at any point during the year has met the criteria. Thoughts?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site.  As this stands, this isn't a coherent question that's answerable here; in particular, this isn't what an array does in SAS.  You need to get this to where it actually makes sense, and preferably has some code to show what you're thinking, before it can be answered.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I think I stated my problem fairly clearly and I am looking for help as to go about answering this question. I have used arrays to answer similar issues for consecutive days off of some seed value but I am looking to start from scratch here. If you know of a better location to look for help on this question I will post it there.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not questions of this breadth.  Communities.sas.com might have some tolerance for questions like this, I suppose, though you really need more detail to get a good answer anywhere: you don't describe your data structure or give examples, so it's really quite hard to give a good answer even if this were on-topic.

Comment: question seems pretty straight forward.  What's the problem?  Perhaps you could provide a sample of your data and show us what you're having a problem with.  In general, the more thought you put into your questions the more likely you'll get a response that helps you out.